# Creating an instance with a specified name, or renaming an instance name after it got created?

Tags: openstack, eucalyptus

I created 4 instances on OpenStack using `euca-run-instances -k Franck -n 4 ami-00000023f`.

The created instances have the following instance names (as listed on OpenStack's Horizon web interface)

- Server b00b1b04-e9f9-4582-86ca-f5773a465f42-b00b1b04-e9f9-4582-86ca-f5773a465f42
- Server 4d765b51-0511-474c-98f0-ef6199a23c7f-4d765b51-0511-474c-98f0-ef6199a23c7f
- Server 378964ac-630e-4490-b738-383bed6bacb1-378964ac-630e-4490-b738-383bed6bacb1
- Server b00b1b04-e9f9-4582-86ca-f5773a465f42-b00b1b04-e9f9-4582-86ca-f5773a465f42

Is there any way to create an instance with a specified name, or to rename an instance name after it got created?

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.

Comment: Since this question received no answer, I posted it on Quora: https://www.quora.com/unanswered/Is-there-any-way-to-create-an-instance-with-a-specified-name-or-to-rename-an-instance-name-after-it-got-created

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nova rename` to rename an instance.